# I am trying to implement pinia store and filter data from api

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-component, pinia

I am building a website, one page has search and filter conditions features to search for user and get information.
front end i am using Vue 3
things i did:

1. retrieved data from backend api through Axios.
2. store data in an array and show the result as list on webpage.
3. created few filters on left nav bar

I want to do apply filters to the received api data.
functionality i want:

1. when search button clicked, whole list should show up.
2. then, when use select each filter, list should update based on match.

**So, What is the best way to this using pinia store ?**

I am trying above functionality with veu Pinia store. I was able to pass the data, but unable to retrieve it on same component.

```js
const passInfo = testStore()
const docList = testStore().receivedData[0]
async function getList(docName, docLocation) {
  try {
    console.info(name + ' ' + loc)
    var {data} = await axios.get('http://127.0.0.1:5000/doc_list' + '?' + 'search=' + docLocation + '&' + 'name=' + docName);
    if (data.error_message) {
      console.log(data.error_message)
    } else {
      info.value = data.data;
      passInfo.addData(data.data) //pass received api data into pinia store
      const reg = "(?:[01]\\d|2[0123]):(?:[012345]\\d):(?:[012345]\\d)"
      console.log((data.data[0].apts_id[0].time).match(reg)[0])
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error.message);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly, you have data in pinia store and you wish to filter it based on select boxes, if the select boxes are in a single page, and the search is local, not api based, you can do this:

```
<template>
<select v-model="selectedType">...
</template>
import {useMyStore } from "store/location";
const myStore = useMyStore();
const selectedType = ref(""); // v-model of select
function fetchData() {
myStore.fetchData();

};

onMounted(() => {
fetchData();
})

// for local search, use computed properties from vue, lets say you have a select for type;

computed(() => {
myStore.storeData.filter(data => data.type === selectedType.value) 
})
```

Your pinia store would be somewhat like this;

```
const storeData = ref([]);
const fetchData = () => {
//makeCall
.then(res => {storeData.value =  responseValue});
}

return {
storeData,
fetchData,
}
```

If your search is api based, you can do this instead of computed value

```
const selectValue = ref("");

function onSearchBtnClick() {
myStore.fetchData({
type: selectValue.value
})
}

// and your store would have

const fetchData = (params) => {
let url = "www.google.com"
if(params.type !== "") {
url += `?type=${params.type}`
}
axios.get(url).then(res => {
storeData.value = res.data.whatever;
})
}
// if your api has search then just add a loader and you'll be golden
```

Comment: Thank you, I pass the data into pinia store after fetching from api and then want to filter from store. But i think your first approach provided me an idea on how to start and work on it.